# Check if all the fields that share the same ID in the table are correlative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with the following structure: An alphanumeric code for drill holes. And an alphanumeric code of samples belonging to those drill holes.

```
CREATE TABLE samples (
hole VARCHAR(50),
sample VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_01', 'OP00001');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_01', 'OP00002');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_01', 'OP00003');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_02', 'OP00004');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_02', 'OP00005');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_01', 'OP00006');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_03', 'OP00007');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_03', 'OP00008');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_03', 'OP00009');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES ('HOLE_03', 'OP00010');
```

I need to run a query to verify that all samples in a well are correlated with each other, and show the holes that do not meet this.

In this example, the expected output should be **HOLE_01**, since the samples are in the range (OP00001-OP00003, OP00006) (there is a bridge).

Comment: And its not clear what your logic is as to why hole_01 is ok.

Comment: @DaleK thanks. Edited. I'll post what i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned previously, this is a modified Gaps-and-Islands,

Now, **IF** the `Sample` can be used as a sequence, then the following should work.  Otherwise, you would need another column which maintains the proper sequence like an Identity or Date/Time Stamp.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8b82253a44a91fa71f463a01f8ad1dd)**

```
Select Hole
      ,Sample = string_agg(sample,',')
 From (
       Select hole
             ,Sample = concat(min(Sample),case when max(sample)=min(sample) then '' else '-'+max(Sample) end)
        From (
               Select * 
                     ,Grp = row_number() over (order by Sample)
                           -row_number() over (partition by hole order by sample)
                 From samples
             ) A
        Group By hole,grp
      ) src
 Group By Hole
 Having count(*)>1   -- Remove if you want to see all ranges
```

**Results**

```
Hole    Sample
HOLE_01 OP00001-OP00003,OP00006
```